# How is this lock useful anyway?

Tags: java, concurrency

I am relatively new to concurrency. I am practicing concurrency from Oracle website. I am stucked at the following example:-

```
public class MsLunch {
    private long c1 = 0;
    private long c2 = 0;
    private Object lock1 = new Object();
    private Object lock2 = new Object();

    public void inc1() {
        synchronized(lock1) {
            c1++;
        }
    }

    public void inc2() {
        synchronized(lock2) {
            c2++;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to know how is this type of lock useful over using synchronized(this) type lock? And in which situations should this type of lock be preferred?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's useful when you have a single object that needs a finer resolution of exclusion than the object itself. In other words, an object with *multiple* resources that need to be protected but not necessarily from each other.

Being bought up in the pthreads world, this is easy to understand since the mutex and it's protected resource tended to be *always* decoupled - there was never this handy shorthand found in Java for using an object as the lock.

As an example, say each object has a array of a thousand integers and you want to lock a group of a hundred at a time (0xx, 1xx, and so on) for maximum concurrency.

In that case, you create ten objects, one per group of a hundred, and you can lock *individual* parts of the array. That way, if you have a thread fiddling about with the `0xx` and `4xx` blocks, it won't stop another thread from coming in and doing something with the `7xx` block.

Now that's a pretty contrived example but the concept does occasionally show up in reality.

In the specific example you've given, only one thread at a time can come in and increment `c1` concurrently, but a lock on `lock1` still permits another thread to come in and change `c2`.

With a object (`this`) lock, concurrency would be reduced because `c1` and `c2` couldn't be updated concurrently despite the fact that there is no conflict.

Answer (score 1):

Object lock is nothing but you are locking the critical section explicitly by an object. synchronized (this) describes that you are locking the critical section by the current object.

Answer (score 1):

Having two separate locks for `inc1` and `inc2` is useful in situations where you want to make sure that no two concurrent threads can both call the same method at the same time, but where you *do* want to allow two concurrent threads to call different methods on the same object.

In your example, if thread 1 calls `inc1`, thread 2 is blocked from calling `inc1` until thread 1 is done. However, thread 2 is free to call `inc2`.